# install build tools 23.0.2 and sync the project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am building a project in android studio and it seems despite of all the works i have done i cannot solve the error message that says:

> install build tools 23.0.2 and sync project.

this is my gradle file :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.noxel.apppaneladmintry2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android.beacon.common:nrf-beacon-lib-v2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'no.nordicsemi.android.support.v18:scanner:0.1.1'
    compile project(':dfu')}
```

I really have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

[image: SDK MANAGER]

Open the sdk manager from your android studio and check whether the build tool 23.0.2 not installed if not install it and the sync the gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You must Copy file(23.0.2) in the folder , for example this address : 
C:\dev\sdk\android-sdk\build-tools